# UICollectionView: Measure force on tap of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, 3dtouch

I am working on a tiny project where I want to use the 3D touch screen pressure capabilities (e.g. `touch.force`).

Right now I can measure force in my ViewController and it is behaving like I want it:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available {
                // 3D Touch capable
                let force = touch.force
                print("Force: " + force.description)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have one `UIImageView` that presents a picture. I also use an custom `UICollectionView` as overlay, which contains transparent cells and colored cells. What I am trying to achieve is to measure both force, and be able to remove the color from the cells when they are pressed, but I am failing to do both. I can either measure force, or change the color of a cell in the UICollectionView, but not both.

The solution as I see it is to forward `touches` from the UICollectionView to the next view in the hierarchy. But another solution could be to measure both force and register taps on cells from within the custom `UICollectionView`.

My question is, is either of my proposed solutions any good? And if so, how do I achieve them?

Comment: Well, what I learned just now after two days: `touchesMoved` is a valid UIView method that can be implemented in UICollectionView as well. I was not aware and thouht that only ViewControllers could override the `touchesBegan` etc. methods.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `override func touches...` methods are part of UIView, not neccesarily UIViewControllers. This means that implementing the `touchesMoved` and other methods into my custom UICollectionView is perfectly possible and it solved my problem of handling touches and taps at the same time.